# DateGridview with checkbox column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my datagridview there is checkbox column. Based on the values in the database want to check the checkbox in the datagridview during runtime and display it to the user.

```
for (int i = 0; i < supName.Count; i++) 
{
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
     {
         int supId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["supplierId"].Value.ToString());
         if (supId == supName[i])
         {  
             row.Cells["selectSupplier"].Value = true;
         }
     }       
 }
```

For one Item there can be multiple suppliers. When adding a new Item to the database, all the existing suppliers are displayed in a datagridview. In this datagridview there is a checkbox column which allows user to select relevant suppliers.

When retrieving information about an item I want to  check the checkboxes of the suppliers user has selected for that particular item in the, above mentioned datagridview (datagridview with all the existing suppliers).

Above is the code that I have used to check the checkbox but it the checkbox is not selected.
checkbox column name is "selectSupplier".

Thank You

Comment: "_it doesnt work_" is a really really bad error description. Especially if you are looking for others to help you. IMO.

Comment: post some more code and clear on what conditions that check box checked/unchecked

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing and and bound to get wrong answers wasting everybody's time.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..! -

Comment: Wouldn't you want to code the false case also?

Answer (score 0):

Your nested loop checks a row if supName list contains the row's supplierId.  First issue I found was that if you don't have "AllowUserToAddRows" set to false, your inner loop will try to parse a blank row to integer and throw an exception.  This stresses the importance of try-catch blocks and proper error handling.

Your method is also quite inefficient, order[n*m].  Ultimately, most of us will recommend using data binding (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  You can "link" your database table directly to your DataGridView and the supplier ID and check come for free.  You will likely need a simple LINQ command (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) to perform the supplier "exists" verification.

If you don't want to or cannot use data binding, you can perform the same result with just your inner loop and use supName.Contains(supId) for order[m].